# Why isn´t it updating?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The contacts are added by other function to this `lst = []`
I´m building an Address Book with a function that allows you to Delete a contact from a list of lists by mentioning the name:

```
def deletec(lst): 
    name=str(input("Name:"))
    lst = sum(lst, [])
    names = lst[::3]
    numbers = lst[1::3]
    emails = lst[2::3]
    dct = {name: (number,email) for name, number, email in zip(names, numbers, emails)}
    if name in dct:
        del dct[name]
        print("Deleted!")
    else:
        print("Name Doesn´t Exists!")
    list_key_value=[ [k,v] for k,v in dct.items()]
    list_key_value = [[name, *tp] for (name, tp) in list_key_value]
    lst=list_key_value
    return lst
```

Which if your list is this:

```
[['Bruno', '44444', 'bruno@hotmail.com'], ['Mariah', '333', 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Oliver', '3333', 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']]
```

And you want to delete Bruno using only the function it returns this:

```
[['Mariah', '333', 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Oliver', '3333', 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']]
```

But when you ask another function that prints it by alphabetic order it uses the old lst:

```
def arrangebyorder(lst):
  from operator import itemgetter
        print(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0)))
        return lst
```

Printing this:

```
[['Bruno', '44444', 'bruno@hotmail.com'], ['Mariah', '333', 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Oliver', '3333', 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']]
```

I was thinking of doing this to solve this problem, since `list_key_value` is empty if you don´t delete any name from `lst` you do a function where when this variable is empty prints the old `lst` sorted alphabetically else if `list_key_value` is defined you print `list_key_value` sorted alphabetically:

```
def list_sorted(lst,lst_key_value):
  try:
    list_key_value
except NameError:
    from operator import itemgetter
    print(sorted(lst, key=itemgetter(0)))
    return lst
else:
    from operator import itemgetter
    print(sorted(list_key_value, key=itemgetter(0)))
    return list_key_value
```

The problem is that when I do it once lst_key_value is not defined it brings this error:

```
TypeError: list_sorted(lst,lst_key_value) missing 1 required positional argument: 'lst_key_value'
```

Can anybody think in other solution?

Only solutions that allow/work with List of Lists

Comment: Please use proper indentation.

Comment: `sorted` returns a new list. `lst.sort`, will actually sort `lst`.

Comment: You could define a default value of `None`: def list_sorted(lst, lst_key_value=None):` and then check it. You `try/except` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @PeterWood thats no problem in sorting the list since it is being sorted by name and not by other criterion, the problem is really getting the program to understand that I want the "new list" that came from deletec instead of the old lst

Comment: @PeterWood how do you suggest I implement it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems to be unnecessarily complicated. You can just use simple list comprehension to remove entries from your list of addresses. You should probably also introduce a class for your addresses, otherwise your code will quickly become hard to read. The following code seems to do everything that you want at much better readability:

```
class Address(object):
    def __init__(self, name, number, email):
        self.name = name
        self.number = number
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Address(%s, %d, %s)" % (self.name, self.number, self.email)

# your list of addresses
addresses = [
    Address('Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com'),
    Address('Mariah', 333, 'mariah@hotmail.com'),
    Address('Oliver', 3333, 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk')
]

# Print your addresses
# prints: [Address(Bruno, 44444, bruno@hotmail.com), Address(Mariah, 333, mariah@hotmail.com), Address(Oliver, 3333, oliver@yahoo.co.uk)]
print(addresses)

# Remove "Bruno" from your addresses
# replacement for your "deletec()" function
# prints: [Address(Mariah, 333, mariah@hotmail.com), Address(Oliver, 3333, oliver@yahoo.co.uk)]
print([address for address in addresses if address.name != "Bruno"])

# Sort your addresses descending by name
# replacement for your "arrangebyorder()" function
# prints: [Address(Oliver, 3333, oliver@yahoo.co.uk), Address(Mariah, 333, mariah@hotmail.com), Address(Bruno, 44444, bruno@hotmail.com)]
print(sorted(addresses, key=lambda address: address.name, reverse=True))
```

---

Similar list of lists solution, as requested by your edit:

```
addresses = [
    ['Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com'],
    ['Mariah', 333, 'mariah@hotmail.com'],
    ['Oliver', 3333, 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']
]

# prints: [['Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com'], ['Mariah', 333, 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Oliver', 3333, 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']]
print(addresses)

# Remove "Bruno" from your addresses
# prints: [['Mariah', 333, 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Oliver', 3333, 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk']]
print([address for address in addresses if address[0] != "Bruno"])

# Sort your addresses descending by name
# prints: [['Oliver', 3333, 'oliver@yahoo.co.uk'], ['Mariah', 333, 'mariah@hotmail.com'], ['Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com']]
print(sorted(addresses, key=lambda address: address[0], reverse=True))
```

Comment: it has to be a list of lists I can´t use classes

Comment: That's a weird requirement. Though you could still similarly write `['Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com']` instead of `Address('Bruno', 44444, 'bruno@hotmail.com')` and then remove with `[address for address in addresses if address[0] != "Bruno"]` and sort with `sorted(addresses, key=lambda address: address[0], reverse=True)`.

Comment: the thing is I have all set and going in my program with the convertion from list of list to dict and then back to list of list. The printing function is the only problem here can we solve it by what I´ve suggested?

Comment: how can I add contacts to addresses since I have another function that is doing that for me? and also have a function that searches for a name and prints the number and email for that exact name.

Comment: Add an address: `addresses.append(["John", 1234, "john@doe.com"])` , find entries matching a name: `matches = [address for address in addresses if address[0] == "John"]`

Comment: But the problem really becomes when you have to print the deleted list and there isn´t one since you only showed the "items" that were different of the name you inputted.